# XNA Position Change using Math.Sin

Tags: c#, xna

I was wondering why my code isn't entirely working.

```
        int sinval = (int)Math.Sin(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds) * 100;
        mSprite.Position += (new Vector2(5 * sinval, 0));
```

I have this in my update method, and really I just wanted some sort of proof of concept. Anyway, what I wanted it to do was basically just oscillate a little bit on the X-axis. But for some reason, it only adds the sinval once at the beginning so anytime i change one of the values in this code it has a new starting position but that is about it.

I have this in the update method as well.

New Code:

```
        int sinval = (int) (Math.Sin(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds) * 61);
        mSprite.Position += (new Vector2(25 * sinval, 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're rounding the result of `Math.Sin` to an integer. In almost *all* cases, that will give 0. `Math.Sin` returns -1 and 1 for -Math.PI/2 and Math.PI/2 respectively... but in all other cases it'll give 0 after rounding towards 0.

Did you mean to round to integer *after* multiplying by 100?

```
int sinval = (int) (Math.Sin(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds) * 100);
```

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right, however it still doesn't seem to oscillate. It does move now.

Comment: @ksandarusi: Well in what way does it move now?

Comment: You should increase your oscillation amplitude from 5 to something more, in this line: `mSprite.Position += (new Vector2(5 * sinval, 0));`

Comment: It still doesn't oscillate (I increased it to 25). Maybe somehow sinval is always coming up positive?

Comment: Just Debugged it, turns out sinval is always returning a value of 1

Comment: @ksandarusi: I suggest you put some logging in to see what value of `sinval` is being used. How often is this being called? You may want to scale your time as well.

Comment: This is being called at every update iteration which I presume is basically the FPS (60 / second)

Comment: @ksandarusi: Don't presume: log and test.

Comment: I double checked. Its 60 iterations per second (Logged and looked up references to it)

Comment: @ksandarusi: So what are the logged values of `Math.Sin(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds) * 100`?

Comment: @ksandarusi: That sounds very unlikely - 1 *after* multiplication by 100? Have you logged `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` as well?

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Sin()` is always between -1 and 1.
Casting that to `int` always returns `0`.

You want to cast after multiplying it by 100.